# processing different quality images with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am analyzing  an image for finding brown objects in an image. I am thresholding an image and taking darkest parts as brown cells. However depending on the quality of an image objects cannot be identified sometimes. Is there any solution for that in OpenCV Python, such as pre-processing the gray scale  image and defining what brown means for that particular image?

The code that I am using to find brown dots is as follows:

def countBrownDots(imageFile):
    im = cv2.imread(imageFile)
    #changing color space
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = increaseBrighntness(gray)
    l1,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    thresh = ndimage.gaussian_filter(thresh, 16)
    l2,thresh = cv2.threshold(thresh,70,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    thresh = ndimage.gaussian_filter(thresh, 16)
    cv2.imshow("thresh22",thresh)
    rmax = pymorph.regmax(thresh)
    nim = pymorph.overlay(thresh, rmax)
    seeds,nr_nuclei = ndimage.label(rmax)
    cv2.imshow("original",im)
    cv2.imshow("browns",nim)

Here is an input image example:

[image]

Comment: Hello, first you should look to HSV space, it is easier to find particular colors in this space. Second, you should show an image of your problem to help us understanding the problem.

Comment: the image is here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vmjqu.jpg

Comment: Building on what biquette said, you should also probably build a histogram out of the Hue image, and see if taking the image regions with a hue value in a given range would already solve the problem. Note: sometimes you can solve a problem by finding all that is NOT what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the image in HSV color space, here are the 3 planes stacked side by side

[image]

Although people have suggested segmenting on the basis of hue, there is actually more discriminative information in the saturation and value planes. For this particular image you would probably get a better result with the gray scale (i.e. value plane) than with the hue. However that is no reason to discard the color information.

As proof of concept (using Gimp) for color segmentation,  I just randomly picked a brown spot and changed all colors with a color distance  of less than 60 from that spot to green to get this:

[image]

If you play with the parameters a bit you will probably get what you want. Then write the code. 
I tried pre-processing [mean shift filtering](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#pyrmeanshiftfiltering) to posterize the image, but that didn't really help.

Comment: I can count number of objects changing to grayscale and using thresholding for this particular image, but when the image changes it does not work. I have to manipulate the parameters in accordance to the image. I would like to do something generic for all that kinds of images. Is that something possible?

Comment: Hand tune the parameters for a number of images, then use those images to train a classifier. OpenCV has a number to choose from, see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html. I would probably go for the support vector machine, because if anything is going to work, but it is a bit of a pain at first.